# How to change your computer's IP? (using proxies)

Tags: c#

I want to change a computer's IP (the kind of IP ipchicken.com or whatismyipadress.com shows you). I don't know how to go about this. :/
Anyway, how would I do this? I've tried this:

```
      WebProxy myProxy = new WebProxy("http://69.136.69.228:27977/", true);
                 myProxy.Credentials = CredentialCache.DefaultNetworkCredentials;
                 req.Proxy = myProxy;
```

Thanks for all your help in advance.

Answer (score 3):

The *external* IP is set by your provider - you can't change it on your computer.

Comment: Oh, well I mean the kind of IP that ipchicken.com shows you. And it "changes" with a VPN or a proxy site. I want to do that but in a program.

Comment: @George Yes, that is the external IP that you can not change. If you connect to a VPN or Proxy, you are using the IP Address that this one assigns you, and it's the IP Address that they received from some Provider. Just with your PC and an internet connection you cannot choose your external IP.

Comment: Okay well how do I use the IP address that it assigns me?